# Delete image from RichEditBox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, richeditbox

I'm inserting an image from a `URL` into a `RichEditBox` like so:

```
// Create a MemoryStream from uri, and insert into richeditbox
System.IO.Stream stream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync("some url");
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
this.richEditBox.Document.Selection.InsertImage(40, 40, 0, Windows.UI.Text.VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "image", memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

Which works fine, but I can't delete (using the onscreen keyboard) the image when pressing `backspace`!

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The answer was simple - just needed to *set* `Selection.StartPosition`

```
this.richEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition--;
this.richEditBox.Document.Selection.Delete(Windows.UI.Text.TextRangeUnit.Object, 1);
```

`StartPosition` is set to `EndPosition` for `Document.Selection` by default, so trying to delete was just doing nothing (since nothing was *selected*).

**Note:** Override `KeyDown` event of `RichEditBox` and add the above to `VirtualKey.Back` key press to get desired results from the onscreen keyboard!